# Integrating jQuery plugin calls inside AngularJS Directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, plugins, directive

I've been working on converting a plain static website into an AngularJS website - just to also improve my skills on that.

So far, I've done routes and looking good so far.

Now on the home page, I made slider images load using **ng-repeat** directive and it's also working. But I noticed something that the slider itself isn't working its supposed functionality. So I found out that the jQuery functions I made on a separate js file isn't loading at all. And I also found out that this can be achieved by integrating the plugin calls inside a directive.

So, I made this:

```
app.directive('featuredSlider', [function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        $(elem).owlCarousel({
            itemsCustom: [
                [0, 1],
                [600, 2],
                [1200, 4]
            ],
            autoPlay: 3000
        });
    }
};}]);
```

I'm using **OwlCarousel** for the slider and it's not being triggered using the one I did above.

By the way, this is how my controller look like:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
$scope.featuredImages = []; }
```

The **featuredImages** array above has the image URLs for the slider.

And then, this is the part where the slider is.

```
<div class = "featured owl-carousel owl-theme featured-slider">
     <div class = "item" ng-repeat = "featured in featuredImages">
       <img ng-src = "{{featured.img}}" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Anyone who can help me out? I've tried out several methods but still not showing up and working.

Comment: I've also tried doing this:

`$(element).owlCarousel(scope.$eval(attrs.featuredSlider));`

Still, no chance of making it work!

Answer (score 0):

Use the controller of the directive and put the third-party library as a service so you can inject the dependency in the directive controller.

Comment: How can I achieve this?

**HomeController** only have data arrays that are on **ng-repeat** inside the page.

Can you help me out with this? I'm seriously stuck in this part.

Answer (score 0):

Create the dependency in this way:
f.e:

```
//Import moment.js into your page as always
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.js"/>

//Before your main app module is declared, declare a momentjs module
angular.module('momentjs',[])
  //And on the momentjs module, declare the moment service that we want
  // available as an injectable
  .factory('moment', function ($window) {
    if($window.moment){
      //Delete moment from window so it's not globally accessible.
      //  We can still get at it through _thirdParty however, more on why later
      $window._thirdParty = $window._thirdParty || {};
      $window._thirdParty.moment = $window.moment;
      try { delete $window.moment; } catch (e) {$window.moment = undefined;
      /*<IE8 doesn't do delete of window vars, make undefined if delete error*/}
    }
    var moment = $window._thirdParty.moment;
    return moment;
  });
```

and then put the directive in this way to assign their own controller:

```
 angular.module("example").directive('exampleDirective', [function () {
    return {            
        templateUrl: 'path',
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude:true,
        controller: 'myDirectiveController'
    };
 }]).controller('myDirectiveController',myDirectiveController);


 function myDirectiveController($scope , $element, $attrs, moment ) {
        //and now you can use this thir party library in the directive controller.
    }
```